# Mission: Be the Vox Populi (badge and all)

Tags: discussion, voting

My name is Laura; I work at Stack Exchange, and I am excited to see you all here. I want to help this community grow and help you all get to know how Stack Exchange works if this is your first time participating in a Stack Exchange community.

---

### Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to use all of your daily allocated votes for one day.

This site is accumulating a fair amount of good content, both questions and answers. Most these posts, though, have low scores. [Voting early and often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) is essential for new communities. Not only does it indicate which content the community thinks is the best quality, the reputation awarded from upvotes allows you to [earn new privileges](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges) on the site like editing tags, voting to close low-quality questions, and more.

**In addition to that, you can earn some nifty badges for voting:**

[image: Bronze badge: supporter]

A lot of you have already earned the [supporter badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/6/supporter) for casting your first upvote. Great job; you're ready to aim for the next one.

[image: Bronze badge: suffrage]

Only *three* of you have earned the [suffrage badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/62/suffrage) for using 30 votes on questions or answers in a day.*

[image: Bronze badge: vox populi]

*No one* has earned the [vox populi](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/71/vox-populi) badge yet! This badge requires that you use up [your 30 allocated votes in one day](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up), plus an extra 10 votes on questions only.

**Let's see how many people can earn these badges over the next week.**

Please vote by the same standards you normally would use: vote up well-written, useful content, and vote down content that needs work. It's always nice to propose suggestions for improvement if you vote down, or edit a post if you know enough about the subject to do so.

The more voting that occurs, the easier it is for great content to rise to the top and the easier it is to draw attention to posts that might need a little more love.

Keep up the good work, and good luck!

<sub>* a "day" - for the purposes of badges (and most other things on this site) - is based on UTC time, not your own time zone.</sub>

Comment: Nice Challenge Laura :) I think up voting this questions is a good start! **Edit** As soon as I typed that I realised meta has a different vote count!

Comment: [Just go vote up all my answers](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy?tab=answers) ;-)

Comment: I realize @metadaddy's comment is a joke, but seriously, don't just click through and blindly upvote, for any one particular user or just going through and upvoting each answer on any given question. We'll know if you didn't actually read the content or if you're voting only for your friends, and your votes will be invalidated. Trust me. :)

Comment: Yes - was joking! I'm looking through the questions now and notice that there are lots of substantial questions with 0 or 1 upvotes. I think folks forget that a good question has as much value as a good answer!

Comment: So, I went back through questions with my favorite tags (and a few other tags I hadn't looked at yet) and picked up some new and useful knowledge, adding in some comments too, all the while vote-vote-voting!  Happy little votes.  Lot's of fun.  Good strategy if you are looking to gain some knowledge and shower the deserving massing with your votes in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Laura - We're making progress!  I noticed that you didn't mention the Civic Duty Silver Badge...perhaps another challenge would be for people to try to earn that?  I found that reading older questions/answers was a great way to pick up some knowledge and upvoting (or downvoting) the best answers and questions while doing it was simple enough.

Comment: @Peter, just noticed you'd clocked that one up. Need to get some more badges myself!! Stoked that I have edit privileges now though, was driving me nuts :)

Comment: @PeterKnolle I didn't mention the silver badge because there were a bunch of other options for similar achievements at a lower level...300 seems like a daunting number if you haven't been voting much. (Congrats on earning the Civic Duty badge, though! That's great.) Might propose that at another time, though, since people are responding pretty well to this challenge. :)

Comment: mission acomplished :)

Answer (score 6):

Achievement unlocked!

[image]

Comment: is that gonna be a linked Answer :-)  +1

Comment: Now 7 of us with the badge. Anymore takers? :)

Comment: Will get to work ;)

Comment: If we could only earn this badge over and over and over again :-)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90499/the-vox-populi-badge-is-multiplying